# Corona: How to make linearDamping work with setGravity( 0, 0 )

Tags: coronasdk

I'm quite new to Corona and I try to develop a icehockey-like game (view from top). Thus, I don't need gravity. If I want to push the puck - wo can I simulate the friction of the ice in this mode?

I use linearDamping but the puck won't reduce it's speed over time. What am I doing wrong?

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()
physics.setGravity( 0, 0 )

local backGroup = display.newGroup();
local stoneGroup = display.newGroup();

local ground = display.newImageRect(backGroup, "assets/images/background-ice.png", 723, 1400 )
ground.x = display.contentCenterX
ground.y = display.contentCenterY

local activeStone = display.newImageRect( stoneGroup, "assets/images/puck.png", 150, 150 )
activeStone.x = display.contentCenterX
activeStone.y = display.contentHeight
activeStone.linearDamping = 100

physics.addBody( activeStone, "dynamic", { radius = 150, bounce = 0 }     )


local function pushPuck ()
  activeStone:applyForce( 0, - 100, activeStone.x, activeStone.y)
end

activeStone:addEventListener( "tap", pushPuck )
```

Comment: I notice the documentation adds the object to physics, then sets the linearDamping property after. Have you tried doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you might need a friction joint.

See http://www.sdknews.com/cross-platform/corona/tutorial-physics-joints-explained-part-1

> The friction joint is extremely simple to configure. It’s used to
>   simulate top-down friction between two objects. This can be useful for
>   simulating both translational (directional) friction and angular
>   (rotational) friction between two joined objects.
>
> Two example scenarios involving a friction joint are:
>
> 1. Simulating the stone in a curling match. In this case, you could use a
>      friction joint on the stone as it moves down the ice, and as the
>      player (“sweepers”) alter the state of the ice in front of the stone,
>      you could adjust both the directional and rotational friction of the
>      joint.
> 2. Simulating a golf ball rolling across different types of
>      terrain. In this case, the friction would be extremely low while the
>      ball was on the green, but if the ball crossed into taller grass or
>      sand, the friction could be increased significantly to slow it down.